# MongoDB production client certificates

Tags: ubuntu, mongodb

I'm moving a mongodb server to production on my Ubuntu machine.
I got an ssl certificate signed by a third party and installed it on the server.
Clients are able to connect to it using their system's CA and validate the server's identity.

However, the mongodb website mentions client certificates.
Am I able to generate them since the CA is a third party?
I tried using openssl to generate these by passing my server's certificate and key, but it is also asking for a `server.srl` which I do not have.
I'm not sure what to do to generate these, or if I need them. I assume they would be an added layer of security as I will be able to verify client's identity in addition to them verifying mine.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

"Am I able to generate them since the CA is a third party?" No!

In order to generate a certificate (i.e. sign a certificate request) you need the private key of the singing certificate. And this key is private, (i.e. secret) as the name implies.

You can ask the 3rd party for another certificate. This would be then a **client** certificate. However, perhaps this company offers only **server** certificates.

You can create the CA certificate and the client certificate by yourself. In MongoDB configuration you can specify CA separately for client and server certificates.

In MongoDB you can use a client certificate "just" as certificate or you can use it for authentication instead of username/password.

Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41302023/how-security-in-mongodb-works-using-x-509-cert/75043317#75043317 to get an overview.